# Проблема с выводом графика

Tags: python, python-3.x, dsp

Пытаюсь вывести график оцифрованной синусоиды, но бестолку- выводится только графическое окно без графика. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from math import sin, pi
from pylab import *
import os

xmax = 10 #интервал в секундах
x = 0
freq = 4  #частота дискретизации в Гц
ff = 0.6
xstep = 1 / freq
bits = 6
mult = 1 << (bits - 1)
result = []

while x < xmax:
   y = math.sin(x*ff) 
   dig = int(y * mult)
   result.append(dig)
   x += xstep 
   plt.plot(x,y)
   plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

График нужно отрисовавать один раз, и нужно передавать список

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from math import sin, pi
from pylab import *
import os

xmax = 10 #интервал в секундах
x = 0
freq = 4  #частота дискретизации в Гц
ff = 0.6
xstep = 1 / freq
bits = 6
mult = 1 << (bits - 1)
result = []

while x < xmax:
   y = math.sin(x*ff) 
   dig = int(y * mult)
   result.append(dig)
   x += xstep 

plt.plot(result)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Я немного затянул с ответом, но поправил код-стайл, а также добавил в отображении использование реальных значений оси абсцисс:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

xmax = 10  # интервал в секундах
x = 0.0
freq = 4  # частота дискретизации в Гц
ff = 0.6
xstep = 1 / freq
bits = 6
mult = 1 << (bits - 1)

xs = []
ys = []
digs = []

while x < xmax:
    y = math.sin(x * ff)
    dig = int(y * mult)
    xs.append(x)
    ys.append(y)
    digs.append(dig)
    x += xstep

plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.plot(xs, digs)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```